# Custom Directive Not Working Within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Hello All: This is my first time asking a question here....

billWatch.HTML

```
        <ul class="border-and-bg vote-unordered-list bill-link-font">
            <li><a ng-click='bill.yea = bill.yea + 1;ctrl.voteYea(1, bill.id, bill.yea)'>Yea</a>:{{bill.yea}} | <a ng-click='bill.nay = bill.nay + 1; ctrl.voteYea(0, bill.id,bill.nay)'>Nay:{{bill.nay}}</a> | **<a ng-click="showComments()">{{filtered.length}} comments</a>**
            </li>
        </ul>


                    <div ng-mdoel='ctrl.commentsSection' ng-repeat='($index, comment) in ctrl.billComments | reverseComments | filter: comment.bill_id = bill.id as filtered' class="comments-container" >

                    <div>
                        <show-comment></show-comment>
                        <ul>

                            <li>{{comment.user_name}} | {{comment.comment}} </li>
                        </ul>

<!--                         <ul>
                            <li ng-bing-html>
                                <my-comment></my-comment>
                            </li>
                        </ul> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

billwatch.ctrl.js

```
(function(){
angular
.module('ccApp')
.controller("BillWatchCtrl', function BillWatchCtrl(){

})
})();
```

showComment.dir.js

```
angular.module('ccApp')
    .directive('showComment', function(){

        function link(scope,element,attrs){

            scope.showComments = function(){

                console.log('showComment');
            }

        }
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link:link
        };
    })
```

I've omitted most of the controller code. I'm only trying to log 'showComment' in the console `on-click` of a anchor tag. It works outside of the `ng-repeat` block but not inside of it. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can improve your question by formatting your code for readability and to eliminate scrolling.

Comment: In order to attract more users willing to help you, I would recommend that you state your problem more clearly, not only saying what you want but also what the problem with the current code is. Maybe you can also reduce it even further as to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: did ng-repaet rendered at least one of the comments, i mean my be your filters output no single comment, ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:*
We could make a much tinier example or actually recommend to use different approaches, but since it seems you are still in the 'technical exploration' phase of your project, I'm simply gonna give you a hand with exactly what you ask `:)`.

---

The problem you have is that the `scope` that gets passed to the `link` function of your directive is not the same as the one **outside** your `ng-repeat`.
That is because the `ng-repeat` directive creates **a new `scope`** for each element.

---

If you want to attach a `function showComments` on the **outside** scope from within your `ng-repeat`, you'd have to do, in the `link` callback:

```
scope.$parent.showComments = function () {/*...*/};
```

Instead of:

```
scope.showComments = function () {/*...*/};
```

However, this way, you're re-assigning your parent's `$scope.showComments` function **for every comment**. Once would be enough!

Thus, I suggest simply pulling your `<show-comment />` element **outside** the `ng-repeat`. The directive will be attached to its container's `scope` and will properly set your `showComments` function where you expect it to be, once.

---

Check out the working snippet below, where I simply:

- concatenated all the code you gave us
- moved the `<show-comments />` element up

```js
angular
  .module('ccApp', [])
  .controller('BillWatchCtrl', function BillWatchCtrl() {

  })
  .directive('showComment', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.showComments = function() {
        console.log('showing comments...');
      }
    }
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: link
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ccApp">
  <ul class="border-and-bg vote-unordered-list bill-link-font">
    <li><a ng-click='bill.yea = bill.yea + 1;ctrl.voteYea(1, bill.id, bill.yea)'>Yea</a>:{{bill.yea}} | <a ng-click='bill.nay = bill.nay + 1; ctrl.voteYea(0, bill.id,bill.nay)'>Nay:{{bill.nay}}</a> | **<button ng-click="showComments()">{{filtered.length}} comments</button>**
    </li>
  </ul>

  <show-comment></show-comment>
  <!-- Moved show-comments HERE -->

  <div ng-model='ctrl.commentsSection' ng-repeat="($index, comment) in ctrl.billComments | orderBy: '[]': true | filter: comment.bill_id = bill.id as filtered" class="comments-container">
    <!-- Instead of THERE -->
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>{{comment.user_name}} | {{comment.comment}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```